# Magento 2.1 : Adding a video to a product using REST API

Tags: magento-2.1, video

I am trying to add video media to product using REST API. Example below

```
$data = [   'entry' => [
      'id' => null,
      'media_type' => 'external-video',
      'label' => null,
      'position' => 0,
      'types' => ['image', 'small-image', 'thumbnail'],
      'disabled' => false,
      'content' => [
          'base64_encoded_data' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://img.youtube.com/vi/axwE9q7llEQ/0.jpg')),
          'type' => 'image/jpeg',
          'name' => '0.jpg'
      ],
      'extension_attributes' => [
          'video_content' => [
              'media_type' => 'external-video',
              'video_provider' => 'youtube',
              'video_url' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axwE9q7llEQ',
              'video_title' => 'KęKę',
              'video_description' => null,
              'video_metadata' => null
          ]
      ]   ] ];

$ch = curl_init("http://URL/index.php/rest/V1/products/BICUMD2ndXXX036/media"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

curl_exec($ch);
```

At the end I am receiving new media file ID but in admin I see that some fields like video url or description are empty. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @rafal-kos I've the same issue! Did you found the solution?

Comment: Yes. I am calling first API request and after that I am calling direct sql queries with missing data 

$sql = "UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video SET store_id = 0, url = :url, title = :title WHERE value_id = :valueId";
$connection->query($sql, ['url' => $url, 'title' => $title, 'valueId' => $videoId]);


$sql = "UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET store_id = 0 WHERE value_id = :videoId";
 $connection->query($sql, ['videoId' => $videoId]);
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is struggling with this, it's fixed in Magento 2.1.8 EE:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.8EE.html#web-api

and Magento 2.1.8 CE:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.8CE.html#web-api

Answer (score 0):

In version CE 2.1.11 I need to add the 'all' indication to the URL to circumvent the same problem.
So: 
    http://URL/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/BICUMD2ndXXX036/media
instead of:
    http://URL/index.php/rest/V1/products/BICUMD2ndXXX036/media

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add a video using rest API, check this link I explain what I did :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7153#issuecomment-414727820

Hope it help.